# If i connect to a python websocket will it start a new script or connect to a daemon

Tags: python, daemon, websocket

Clue is in the name. When a websocket connects will it connect to run a new script or start a daemon, if it does start a new script is there a way to pass it on to a daemon script ?
Thankyou !

### Finished

I dont know what the answer to my own question is but i just set up a deamon to run on its own port.

Comment: You need to provide more context. What python websockets implementation are you using?